# Editing the Default Links like "Site Admin" in the Sidebar Meta Section?

Tags: metabox

After creating a new WordPress site, how can I edit the default links like *"Site Admin"* found in the sidebar *"meta"* section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the "Meta" box you see in the sidebar.  These links can't be edited, they're part of the sidebar widget itself.  Your safest bet would be to replace the Meta widget with your own Text widget that lists out whatever links you do want displayed.

Answer (score 3):

@Techboy - do you want to add links to what is already there?  If so, you can create a plugin using `add_action('wp_meta', 'your_wp_meta_function');`

Ours has this function:

```
function your_wp_meta_function() {
    global $base, $current_site;
    echo "<li><a href=\"http://" . $current_site->domain . $current_site->path . "wp-signup.php\" title=\"Create a new blog\">Start a Blog</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href=\"http://" . $current_site->domain . $base . "directory.php\" title=\"Blog Directory\">Blog Directory</a></li>";
}
```